# Counter loop creation and placement within code to handle results

Tags: python, xml, loops, counter

I have some Python code to iterate over a large XML file to parse out certain results within a comma-separated element.

While the code pulls out the results, I need it to count the results as well.
How do I write this loop within my current code, and where should it be placed? Within the loop after my `.split()` function? After?

My code:

```py
#Working python code

#Import libraries
import webbrowser

from lxml import etree

#Parses the file to get the tree paths
tree = etree.parse('g_d_anime.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#Starts the XPATH using findall to verify the elements inside the tree are right
#Might not be necessary, but it's not a bad check to have
tree.findall('WorksXML/Work')

#Opens the output file for the results
h_file = open("xml_stats.html","w")
#Start writing the HTML lines
h_file.write("This block shows the producers and genres for this file.")
h_file.write('<br>')

#These loops first split the string, then select the specific value I want to pull out
for Producers in root.iter('Producers'):
    p = Producers.text.split(',')
    for producer in p:
        #if you require only to display only 'Nitroplus', put '==' in place of '!='
        if producer == 'Aniplex':
            print(p) #This prints all the values in the strings
            h_file.write('<li>' + str(producer) + '</li>') #This only writes the selected value
            h_file.write('<br>')
for Genres in root.iter('Genres'):
    g = Genres.text.split(',')
    for genre in g:
        #if you require only to display only 'Magic', put '==' in place of '!='
        if genre == 'Magic':
            print(g)  #This prints all the values in the strings
            h_file.write('<li>'+ str(genre) + '</li>')  #This only writes the selected value
            h_file.write('<br>')

#Should the counting loop for the above go here? Or within the above loop?

h_file.close()

webbrowser.open_new_tab("xml_stats.html")
```

I'm not sure where to put the count loop, or .sum(), or Counter lines, if that's easier.
The results should show something like:

```
Aniplex: 7
Magic: 9
```

The file has over 1500 records that are structured like this:

```xml
<WorksXML>
  <Work>
    <Title>Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood</Title>
    <Type>TV</Type>
    <Episodes>64</Episodes>
    <Status>Finished Airing</Status>
    <Start_airing>2009-4-5</Start_airing>
    <End_airing>2010-7-4</End_airing>
    <Starting_season>Spring</Starting_season>
    <Broadcast_time>Sundays at 17:00 (JST)</Broadcast_time>
    <Producers>Aniplex,Square Enix,Mainichi Broadcasting System,Studio Moriken</Producers>
    <Licensors>Funimation,Aniplex of America</Licensors>
    <Studios>Bones</Studios>
    <Sources>Manga</Sources>
    <Genres>Action,Military,Adventure,Comedy,Drama,Magic,Fantasy,Shounen</Genres>
    <Duration>24 min. per ep.</Duration>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
    <Score>9.25</Score>
    <Scored_by>719706</Scored_by>
    <Members>1176368</Members>
    <Favorites>105387</Favorites>
    <Description>"In order for something to be obtained, something of equal value must be lost." Alchemy is bound by this Law of Equivalent Exchange—something the young brothers Edward and Alphonse Elric only realize after attempting human transmutation: the one forbidden act of alchemy. They pay a terrible price for their transgression—Edward loses his left leg, Alphonse his physical body. It is only by the desperate sacrifice of Edward's right arm that he is able to affix Alphonse's soul to a suit of armor. Devastated and alone, it is the hope that they would both eventually return to their original bodies that gives Edward the inspiration to obtain metal limbs called "automail" and become a state alchemist, the Fullmetal Alchemist. Three years of searching later, the brothers seek the Philosopher's Stone, a mythical relic that allows an alchemist to overcome the Law of Equivalent Exchange. Even with military allies Colonel Roy Mustang, Lieutenant Riza Hawkeye, and Lieutenant Colonel Maes Hughes on their side, the brothers find themselves caught up in a nationwide conspiracy that leads them not only to the true nature of the elusive Philosopher's Stone, but their country's murky history as well. In between finding a serial killer and racing against time, Edward and Alphonse must ask themselves if what they are doing will make them human again... or take away their humanity.
    </Description>
  </Work>
...
</WorksXML>
```

I know the loop should look something like:

```py
for pr in producer:
   pr = 0
   if pr in producer:
       producer[pr] = producer[pr] + 1
   else:
       producer[pr] = 1
```

If anyone has a better way to write this, please share.

Comment: Your loop *for pr in producer* makes no sense. Describe what you're trying to achieve

Comment: `@DarkKnight` I was trying to figure out if the loop needed to be written as if it was looping through the newly pulled data, therefore separate, or if I could integrate it into the loop I already built to pull the selected data from the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to count `Aniplex` and `Magic` only, you should put it in the `if` block and then after loops write it to the file:

```py
aniplex_count = 0
magic_count = 0

for Producers in root.iter("Producers"):
    p = Producers.text.split(",")
    for producer in p:
        if producer == "Aniplex":
            aniplex_count += 1
            h_file.write(
                "<li>" + str(producer) + "</li>"
            )
            h_file.write("<br>")
for Genres in root.iter("Genres"):
    g = Genres.text.split(",")
    for genre in g:
        if genre == "Magic":
            magic_count += 1
            h_file.write(
                "<li>" + str(genre) + "</li>"
            )
            h_file.write("<br>")

h_file.write(f"<h2>Aniplex: {aniplex_count}</h2>")
h_file.write(f"<h2>Magic: {magic_count}</h2>")
```

Comment: @SassyG You're welcome, happy coding! :)